# Function not displaying correct results

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, primes, factors

I have a factor finder that I have programmed that is supposed to start by checking if the value entered in the input box is 1 or 0 so it would display "The factor of 1 is 1." or "The factor of 0 is 0.", but when I enter the number 0 into the input box it displays "The factor of 0 is ." but I cannot figure out why. It is probably a simple mistake that I cannot figure out. Here is my code.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javaScript/prime.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Number-->
        <h1>Factor finder</h1>
        <p>Enter a number to find the factors!</p>
        <form name="prime" id="here">
            Number:
            <input class ="enter2" type="text" name="primeinput" size ="20"/>
            <input type="button" name="addnumber" value="Go" onclick="findFactor();"/>
            <br />
            <h2>Results</h2>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
//counters
var numbernum = 0;
var numinput = 1;
//function
function findFactor(){
    var array = new Array();
    //get input
    thenumber=document.prime.primeinput.value;
    //special circumstances for 1 and 0
    if (thenumber == 1 || thenumber == 0){
        amount = "The factor of ";
        verb = " is ";
    } else{
        amount = "The factors of ";
        verb = " are ";
    }
    //factor finder
    for (i=1; i<thenumber + 1; i++){
        //check to see if the number is a factor
        if(thenumber % i == 0){
            //check if the number is 1 or 0 to state the factors are 1 or 0
            //not working with 0             
            if(thenumber == 1 || thenumber == 0){
                if (thenumber == 1){
                    array[0] = 1;
                } else if (thenumber == 0){
                    array[0] = 0;
                }
            //if the number isn't 0 or 1
            } else if(thenumber != 1 && thenumber != 0){
                if (thenumber == numinput){
                    array[numbernum] = "and " + numinput;
                } else{
                    array[numbernum] = numinput;
                    numbernum ++
            }

        }

    }
    numinput ++
}
//append to the HTML
var make = document.createElement("p");
var apply = document.createTextNode(amount + thenumber + verb + array.join(", ") + ".");
make.appendChild(apply);
document.getElementById("here").appendChild(make);
//reset counters and clear array
numbernum = 0;
numinput = 1;
var array = 0;
}
```

Comment: If `thenumber` is `0`, the loop terminates immediately, since `1 < thenumber + 1` is false.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `else if(thenumber != 1 && thenumber != 0)`, just use `else`. That's just the opposite of the `if` condition, and the `else` is only executed when the `if` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the special cases of `0` and `1`, don't bother with the `for` loop, since you know what the correct results should be. So put the `if` outside the `for`:

```
if (thenumber < 2) {
    array[0] = thenumber;
} else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= thenumber; i++) {
        if (thenumber % i == 0) {
            array.push(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for does not loop because of this:

**for (i=1; i < **0** + 1**

Try to change this to

**for (i=1; i <= thenumber**